# How to declare a string of strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyRow IN ('100','200','300')
```

Trying to do the above by declaring a local variable like this:

```
DECLARE @What VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @What = '100','200','300'
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyRow IN (@What)
```

Is there any way to make this work? Have "tried" this:

```
SET @What = "'100','200','300'"
```

and this:

```
SET @What = ('100','200','300')
```

The first one is the most logical as it can mostly be used in any other language  but SQL. The length of `@What` will vary so I cannot just have one variable for each.

How to declare a local string variable to contain strings?

Comment: "as it can mostly be used in any other language but SQL" Really? Can you name any other language where the system will inspect the contents of a *single* string parameter, find commas inside and decide to instead turn it into *multiple* parameters? I'm not aware of any that act like that. In such a language, how do you pass it a parameter where a comma is a legitimate part of a parameter?

Comment: I'm talking about having strings with single quotes inside a string with double quotes. In SQL double quotes are non-existent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, with a table variable:

```
DECLARE @What TABLE(txt VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @What (txt) VALUES ('100'),('200'),('300')
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyRow IN (SELECT txt FROM @What)
```

Here's [a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce029c/1) to demonstrate the above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better if you would pass your list as a comma seperated list and then convert it into table. Here's a working example:

```
DECLARE @What VARCHAR(MAX) = '100,200,300';
DECLARE @XmlData AS XML = CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@What, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML);
DECLARE @Test TABLE (What INT);


INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT N.value('.',  'INT') FROM @XmlData.nodes('X') AS T(N);

SELECT *
FROM MyTable AS M
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @Test AS T
    WHERE T.What = M.MyRow
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyRow VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('100'),('200'),('300')


DECLARE @What VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @What = '100,200,300'

declare @xml xml

set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@What,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE MyRow IN
(
select 
  t.value('.','varchar(max)') as [MyRow items]
from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as a(t)
)
```